# Add to interest group using Mailchimp API v3

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using this MailChimp api v3 wrapper https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/tree/api-v3

Using the example I can add an email to my list but cannot add it to one of my interest groups.

This is the example code:

```
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
    $result = $MailChimp->post('lists/b1234346/members', array(
                'email_address'     => 'davy@example.com',
                'status'            => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields'      => array('FNAME'=>'Davy', 'LNAME'=>'Jones'),
                'interests'         => array( '2s3a384h' => true )
                )); 
print_r($result);
```

My understanding is the key in that array entry for interests is the ID of the group. I created a group in MailChimp, which has a group title and group names.
I can see an id when I hover over the group title edit button, and also the group name edit button. If I hover over the *"0 subscribers"* for a group name I can see that same id and a group_id. I've tried both values and I get this error:

> Array ( [type] =>
>   http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/error-docs/400-invalid-resource [title] =>
>   Invalid Resource [status] => 400 [detail] => Invalid interest ID:
>   '39561'. [instance] => 12c1ab46-a0b5-4014-8107-08cfa97a9a94 )

I've googled and still can't find the answer. Any help?

Comment: Ok so I did a get which showed me all the members and exposed an alphanumeric id for each group. No idea how you would get it this using the MailChimp console.

Comment: You can get the API interest IDs from `/lists/<id>/interest-categories/<id>/interests`

Comment: Ahh cool!! Thanks TooMuchPete!

Comment: I was able to get to the group/interest ids through MailChimp's API Playground pretty easily.

Comment: This is soo bad comparing to v1 and v2. Now we need to request the names from each category individually!

Answer (score 30):

You can get the Id of the specific `interest option` not the group id, by [going to the playground](https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/playground/)

Then you navigate to your list and group:

[image: navigate to list and group in playground]

When you click on the name of the interest option it will show the option meta data, including it's id:

[image]

Comment: I think I vote your answer because I need to find the interest ID :) ... Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Interests are (can be? must be?) grouped under interest-categories, but you only need the ID of the interest itself, not the ID of the interest-category when setting it for the user.

Your error may be from using the interest-category ID instead of the specific interest ID.

Comment: Urghh, we were just creating an interest title, not an actual group! Doh! @user3029992, mark this as the correct answer please.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. So glad I stumbled across this. About pulled all my hair out.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! MailChimp really should update their documentation to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to capture all of the Interest IDs...

```
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
    $result = $MailChimp->post('lists/b1234346/members', array(
                'email_address'     => 'davy@example.com',
                'status'            => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields'      => array('FNAME'=>'Davy', 'LNAME'=>'Jones')
                )); 
print_r($result);
```

Your `print_r` after not specifying the "interests" key in the post should provide you with an interests array with the IDs telling you they are all marked as false.

```
["interests"]=> array(7) { ["258ad948a1"]=> bool(false) ["8e30162ec8"]=> bool(false) ["f2f79df229"]=> bool(false) ["b4e2f6effc"]=> bool(false) ["4fb0927fef"]=> bool(false) ["f2d1e06470"]=> bool(false) ["9f6c7c4db2"]=> bool(false) }
```